# Was creating PostgreSQL database but getting error with constraint matching key

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

Can anyone tell me what's is wrong and how to fix?
PostgreSQL database creating error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique 
constraint matching given keys for referenced table "shop_item_skus"
```

```
 __tablename__ = "shop_item_skus"

    id = Column( Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True )
    sku_internal_identifier = Column( String(32), nullable=False, primary_key=True )
    name = Column( String(128), nullable=False )
    description = Column( String(256), nullable=False )
    category = Column( String(32) )

    purchaseable = Column( Boolean, nullable=False, default=False )

    soft_currency_cost = Column( Integer )
    hard_currency_cost = Column( Integer )

    steam_sellable = Column( Boolean, default=False,  default=False )


__tablename__ = "shop_sku_prices"

    id = Column( Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True )
    sku_id = Column( Integer, ForeignKey("shop_item_skus.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True )
    currency = Column( String(5), nullable=False )
    unit_price = Column( Integer, nullable=False )

    def __init__(self, sku_id, currency, unit_price):
        self.sku_id = sku_id
        self.currency = currency
        self.unit_price = unit_price
```

Comment: In the table `shop_item_skus` the PK is `id, sku_internal_identifier`.  `shop_sku_prices` is pointing at the `id` column only and that is not going to work.

Comment: You have created a compound primary key for table `shop_item_skus` with the columns (`id,sku_internal_identifier`). A FK reference then must contain **both columns**. 
However, being autogenerated value `id` by itself is unique (at least it should be). So it is not necessary to have `sku_internal_identifier` as part of the PK. 
I think what you want is make `id` the entire PK and `sku_internal_identifier` as a unique value.  Sorry, but I do not know how to specify this in your obscurification  (ORM) language.